# Rails application installer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I am making a rails cms and I have wondered if there is a plugin or script, which automatically installs the application?

Thanks!

Comment: By install you mean uploading the app to the deployment server and initialize the database and other dependencies ?

Comment: No, just like when you install a phpbb forum or wordpress blog...
Something like script, which to configure the database, rake it and install missing gems...

Comment: You are looking at a combination of `ansible`/`chef`/`manual-config` + `capistrano`. However, if this is just a temporary hosting, you may wish to check heroku or other platforms that make what you are looking for, simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a capistrano recipe for it.
You can even remotely install the application, or, install in batch on different servers, or, update QA/ staging/ production, run auto tests, do a lot of linux console work, and so on...

Its good. Check it out.
http://capistranorb.com

update: capistrano link updated

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer. no.
You have to write such a wizard on your own.

You know the drill ... check for a custom config file, if it doesn't see one, run a rake task to create the database tables, install gems etc.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Rails isn't an application. It's a framework. You can't "auto-install" it. You must define all your dependencies by yourself.

There are some shortcuts however. To create a new application for example, you can do in command line :

```
rails my_new_app
```

Then you'll have to start coding it. Take a look at the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) if that's where you don't know what to do.

If what you're looking for is an easy to install Rails CMS, you could take a look at [radiant](http://radiantcms.org/) which does that.

Comment: Pfff, you don`t understand what I want at all! I know what rails is, is just want to create a installer for my app!!!!

Comment: No need for attitude when someone is trying to help you. I think the responders are right ... you have to write this yourself. No plugin can know your dependencies and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Capistrano,](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano) although not an installer or packager, does greatly simplify deploying a Rails application from your development environment onto your hosting server.

Comment: Ye, but I want to make it easy to install this application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to deploy this app to a production server, or to a clients PC?

If you want a windows style installer, there isn't really much available as rails isn't designed to run that way.
You can, however, still do it.
My recommendation would be using NSIS with some custom batch scripts in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Download some open source Rails apps and have a look at their install scripts. I looked at [Fat Free CRM](http://www.fatfreecrm.com/) for inspiration and found it useful.

Your users will need to specify their database type, username, and password; create the database and migrate it or load the schema; install any gems required in `config/environment.rb`; specify their webserver setup and more.

Writing your own rake task is a nice way to bundle this stuff into as few commands as possible, and should be ok to run on any platform.